# php - ошибка синтаксиса

Tags: php

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чём ошибка? 17 строка. Заранее спасибо!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не могли бы вы прислать в текстовом формате?Лично мне сидеть считать строки не хочется.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Вы упустили точку с запятой в 16-й строке.

```
function factorial($num){
    $factorialIter = function($num, $acc) use (&$factorialIter){
        ...
    };
    return $factorialIter($num, 1);
}
```

*P.S. На будущее, если вы просите людей потратить свое время, то будьте добры потратить свое и писать код в текстовом виде.*

Comment: Да кому надо париться код писать? Вы же ответили на вопрос, а значит можно надеяться, что и в следующий раз кто-то да ответит

Comment: Интересно, минус за то что смог ответить и помог человеку, не смотря ни на что?

Comment: Спасибо большое! Действительно, глупо поступил, осознаю. Ехал на работу, с телефона не получалось текстом отправить, чёрт дёрнул отправить с мобилки - любопытство заело. Ещё раз спасибо!

Comment: @Bookin возможно кто-то согласен с моим высказыванием и тем самым таким образом показывает, что так поступать не совсем верно. Воспитательная мера. Но этого мы не узнаем. Я еще минус не поставил, но просто в следующий раз желательно добиться корректного оформления вопроса

Comment: Я в целом понимаю что "наказывают", но, считаю это глупо, и хотел бы получить комментарий за минус. Пытаются заставить людей не помогать людям, что это за сообщество тогда такое. Потратил время, разобрался в вопросе, дал ответ, ответ верен, не является вредным, и тебя еще за это наказывают. Еще и новичков накидываются, в общем не помогают задержать или оставаться  в сообществе.